# Listening for touch events in background in an application

Tags: android, events, service, background

Is there any way to fire my applications's click event if user long pressed screen in chrome or other mobile application, while my application is not running.

Comment: I think this would be a combination of service, broadcast and an access to device admin settings. I'm not sure how to though. Leaving a comment to get notified.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can use a floating view in service and override onTouch event in that floating view to listen touch event of screen. to make floatlistening not visible on screen set their size 1dp or set visibility to invisible.
[here](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064) is link about floating view.

**EDIT**
[here](http://jhshi.me/2014/11/09/monitor-screen-touch-event-in-android/index.html#.WpffKXJuaM8) is another link for listening touch event in background.